# Aggregations elasticsearch 5

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

In my elastic search index has following type of entries.

```
{
  "_index": "employees",
  "_type": "employee",
  "_id": "10000",
  "_score": 1.3640093,
  "_source": {
    "itms": {
      "depc": [
        "IT",
        "MGT",
        "FIN"
      ],
      "dep": [
        {
          "depn": "Information Technology",
          "depc": "IT"
        },
        {
          "depn": "Management",
          "depc": "MGT"
        },
        {
          "depn": "Finance",
          "depc": "FIN"
        },
        {
          "depn": "Finance",
          "depc": "FIN"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Now I an trying to get unique department list including department code (depc) and department name (depn).

I was trying following but it doesn't give result what I expected.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {},
  "aggs": {
    "departments": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "itms.dep.depc",
        "size": 10000,
        "order": {
          "_term": "asc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "department": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "itms.dep.depn",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks You

Comment: Is it possible for depc to have multiple depn or vice-versa ?

Comment: It's not possible

Answer (score 1):

From your agg query, it seems like the mapping type for `itms.dep` is object and not [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html)

> Lucene has no concept of inner objects, so Elasticsearch flattens
>   object hierarchies into a simple list of field names and values.

Hence, your doc has internally transformed to :

```
{
  "depc" :        ["IT","MGT","FIN"],
  "dep.depc" : [ "IT","MGT","FIN"],
  "dep.depn" :  [ "Information Technology", "Management", "Finance" ]
}
```

i.e. you have lost the association between `depc` and `depn`

To fix this :

1. You need to change your object type to nested
2. Use [nested aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html)

The structure of your existing agg query seems fine to me but you will have to convert it to a nested aggregation post the mapping update